# How to remove non visible characters from sed output to a file

Tags: sed, terminal, ls

I am trying to list all the directories inside another directory and put it onto a file using sed.

Command Used:

```
ls -ld <directory path>/* | sed 's/^.*\(what.*\).*\//\1/'
```

What it print onto terminal:

```
what_111
what_222
```

When I put it onto a file, this is what I see: Un-visible characters getting put onto file.

```
what_111^[[0m^[[K
what_222^[[0m^[[K
```

How do I remove them from sed output while putting onto file ? Any comments would be helpful.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream

Comment: Yes it did work with the following command:
ls -ld <directory path>/* | sed -u 's/^.*\(test.*\).*\//\1/' | sed -u 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]//g'
This works fine on the terminal but when I put it on the shell script the sed isn't working. Any issue ?

Comment: Do not parse ls. Why do you use `ls` and then remove colors? Just do not use ls.... You are asking XY question.

Comment: @KamilCuk Well I am trying to get the list of directories inside another directory and putting in the file.. While doing so faced saw this un-viewable symbols on the text file.. TO resolve that Used the sed.

Comment: `on the text file` No, on `ls` output. Does the _filename_ itself contains unprintable characters or does `ls` output them? `When I put it onto a file` How do you "put it onto a file"? `Un-visible characters getting put onto file.` How do you inspect the file content?

Comment: When I execute  in the terminal I dont see the characters. But when I put the output onto a file > file.txt, then I see those characters.. I am using the sed because I wanted to print only the end directory name and not the entire path of the directory.

Comment: ls -ld <dir path>/* | sed 's/^.*\(test.*\).*\//\1/' | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]//g ' > file_list.txt

Comment: Why is the string `(test.*)` showing up in the sed scripts in your comments, e.g. `sed 's/^.*(test.*).*\//\1/'`? That seems completely unrelated to anything mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be starting off on the wrong track (trying to parse the output of `ls` and, I'd bet, having `ls` aliased to `ls --color`) and then trying to add code to fix the problems that you caused by doing so. To list the names of directories under a directory just do this:

```
find /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%P\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to list all the directories inside another directory and put it onto a file using sed.

That's not possible to do with `sed` - sed is a "Stream EDitor", it can't list directories.

[Do not parse ls.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

`find` the directories.

```
find another_directory/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d > a_file
```

Comment: But this above command prints the entire path of the directories. I just wanted to print the names of the directory alone inside the other directory [not the full hierarchical path] and also not all the sub-directories inside the other.

Comment: `find ... -printf '%f\n'` see `man find`. Or  `find ... | sed 's~.*/~~'`. or `cd another_directory; find . .... | cut -c3-`

Comment: Tried.. Like..
find <dirpath>/ -maxdepth 1 -type d |sed "s/^.*\(test.*\).*\//\1/"
But still the sed doesn't remove of all the details before test, but the same sed works with ls output.

Answer (score 0):

Tried combing some of the response above and got it working. Below is the command I tried and its working.

```
find <directory path> -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed 's/^.*\(test.*\)/\1/g' |tail -n +2 > file_list.txt
```